# Блокировать input range по клику

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как я могу заблокировать input type range по клику ?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="range" />
    <button>block/ unblock</button>
  <div>
</template>
```

- поменять его цвет на синый (когда он заблокирован)
  если он не заблокирован -  цвет серый

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="range" />
<button onclick="changeDisabled()">block/ unblock</button>
```

```
function changeDisabled(){
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var val = input.getAttribute('disabled');
    if(val == null) input.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    else input.removeAttribute ('disabled');

}
```

Comment: по-умолчанию в хроме цвет range синий когда активен, и серый когда заблокирован. в других браузерах это тоже визуализируется.

Comment: настроить свойства ксс для тегов input (тем более range) весьма сложно. я лично для этих целей использую костыли (наложение стилизованных под range блоков поверх input. + js)

Comment: нужно на vue ))

Comment: Ну так перепишите на vue